# How to preemptively determine when email has arrived?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, email

I want to listen for incoming emails and, if they are of a certain format, intercept them (process them and preferably prevent them from proceeding on to the email inbox).

What event should I monitor for this? Is there something like a "FileSystemWatcher" that knows when email is incoming, or...???

Comment: Please don't cross post essentially the same question in multiple places.  It gets hard to keep track of what you are asking and is likely to put people off answering at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible.

The reason is this: What email account are you listening to? And what is raising the event? You reference the file watcher, but do you see how simplistic a file watcher is compared to email? What if the current user has 10 email accounts - what do you expect the OS to do? Raise a NewEmail event for each email? And, what if they are running Outlook, Windows Live Mail, Windows 8 Mail, and some other client. How would the OS know in the first place? If each client is monitoring a different client, what are you expecting to happen? For this reason, what you are asking is not possible.

> The short of it is: the OS is not monitoring user email accounts.

However, if what you are attempting to accomplish is to monitor an email account and respond when that account receives new email, **this is not a Windows 8 question** anymore. This is a POP or EAS question where you connect to and monitor an account just like an email client does. You would not be wise to do this on the client, either. Since Windows 8 apps are not always running - a server/service would be a smarter approach.

Specifically to your question, though: not possible.

Good luck, I hope that answers your question.

Comment: The email account would be for the default, baked-in email client - both on Windows 8 and for WP8. I find it hard to imagine that it's not possible to know (programmatically) when an email arrives. The system obviously knows when an email arrives; that's how it can update the email tile with a badge count. I'm thinking a background operation would keep tabs on incoming emails - when the "right" ones arrive, they are dealt with.

Comment: I'm thinking Raw Notifications (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Raw-notifications-sample-3bc28c5d) might be in my future